# How to use md-icon with md-autocomplete in Angular-Material Design?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, material-design

Is there any way to place md-icon in md-autocomplete

```
   <md-autocomplete 
       md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
       md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
       md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
       md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
       md-item-text="item.display"
       placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">

   <md-icon class="material-icon">search</md-icon> // ofcourse, I think It won't work

  </md-autocomplete>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/rajagopalx/pen/RrMQXx?editors=1000)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not yet posible with angular-material (out of the box). 
See this [closed issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6150).

As a workaround, you can do somethihg similar with a bit of custom CSS.

See an example on this [working plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoxBeL).

**HTML:** (note *id* and *md-input-name*)

```
<md-autocomplete id="custom" md-input-name="autocompleteField".../>
```

**CSS**:

```
#custom input[name="autocompleteField"]  {
    background: url(images/search.icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px 7px;
    padding: 0px 35px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Suppose i want to be able to click the icon, as for opening a menu dropdown. How am i suppose to detect a click on it if i am using it as background?

Answer (score 4):

As this is one of the top links when someone is looking to add icon to angular material autocomplete

If you want to do the same using new angular material, it can be easily done by using mat-icon after input field

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

stackblitz link with an example
https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbmrnjeydjm

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to append the icon to the md-input-container inside the md-autocomplete. The md-input-container is only appended, if you're using the md-floating-label attribute.

**JS**: the timeout and the compile was necessary to make the icon appear. By appending the md-icon-left class, the input receives a padding of 36px, like every other md-input-container that has an icon

**attrs[vm.name]** will use the attribute value as the icon name

```
  ...
  .directive('appendIcon', appendIcon);

  function appendIcon($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var vm = this;
        $timeout(function() {
          var container = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('md-input-container'));

          container.addClass('md-icon-left');
          var icon = $compile('<md-icon class="material-icons">' + attrs[vm.name] + '</md-icon>')(scope);
          container.append(icon);
        });
      }
    };
  };
```

**HTML**: note append-icon="search" and md-floating-label="State"

```
  <md-autocomplete 
   append-icon="search"
   md-floating-label="State"
   id="custom" flex="" 
   required=""
```

Here's a codepen:
http://codepen.io/eydrian/pen/ZLdgwQ

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the method below, to be able to use .svg icons. Not only can I continue using the Material Design icons, but I can also make buttons out of it, to trigger an event, such as opening a menu etc, giving help info etc.

```
<div style="float: left; padding: 25px 10px 0 4px;">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="/images/icons/email.svg" class="input-icon-color"></md-icon>
</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <md-autocomplete 
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
        md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">

        <md-icon class="material-icon">search</md-icon>
    </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

The following style is to imitate the color of the .svg icons when used within an `<md-input-container>`:

```
<style>
.input-icon-color {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I believe the issue is connected with the fact that md-autocomplete has as an md-input-container inside of it.*

This is what I ended up doing to display a row of evenly spaced input fields with the first one being md-autocomplete.

Notably I had to wrap the other two md-input-containers in flexed difs.

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div layout="row" flex layout-align="start start">
      <md-input-container>
      <!-- it looks like in angular material md-icon needs to be surrounded by a div -->
        <div><md-icon class="yellow-fg" md-font-icon="icon-white-balance-sunny"></md-icon></div>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-autocomplete flex usual_attributes_here>
        (...)
      </md-autocomplete>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" flex>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-numeric"></md-icon>
        (...)
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" flex>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-numeric"></md-icon>
        (...)
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]